# How to solve error in qt creator in ubuntu?

Tags: qt-creator

While running a project in qt creator in ubuntu I got the following error: "No rule to make target for 'isledialog.ui' needed by 'ui_isledialog.h'.Stop."

Comment: please provide information what build system are you using? qmake, cmake etc. and how did you enter ui_isledialog.h /isledialog.ui to the project

Comment: I am using qmake but I haven't entered any file named 'ui_isledialog.h/isledialog.ui' to my project, so I don't understand how this error is popping up.I have even deleted my all the .pro.user files but it didn't work out.